# A line tangent to the graph of sin

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

We have the function $f(x)=\sin x$, and a line tangent to the function at 2 different points. 
 The slop of the line is $\alpha$. 
I need to show that $\tan\alpha=\alpha$. 
Here's what I have tried: 
Let $A(x_1;\sin x_1)$ be a point on $f(x)$ where the line with slope $\alpha$ tangent to the functiom. 
$f'(x)=\cos x$, And we get the tangent line to the graph at $A$ is the following: 
$y=\cos(x_1)\cdot x+\sin x_1-x_1\cdot \cos(x_1)$. 
Now let $A'(x_0,\sin(x_0))$ be the other point. 
Thus: 
$$\cos(x_0)=\cos(x_1)=\alpha$$ 
$$\sin(x_0)-x_0\cdot \cos(x_0) = \sin(x_1)-x_1\cdot \cos(x_1)$$
From the first equation we get $x_0=x_1+2\pi k$ or $x_0=-x_1+2\pi k$. 
From the first case, if we plug into the second equation we get: 
$$\cos(x_0)=0$$ So $\alpha=0$ and $\tan\alpha=\alpha$ 
I could not get any progress with the second case. Does anyone have another idea to solve this problem or can help me with the second case? 
Thanks!

Comment: @DavidK $y=\tan x$ (which is also periodic) and $y=x$ have infinitely many intersections both positive and negative.

Comment: @DavidK This problem is from a test to identify mathematically gifted children so that they can start uni at young age. Secondly, This is not the only case. I checked on geogebra a few days ago and I found another case where $tan\alpha=\alpha$ and $\alpha \neq 0$, and the statement in the problem holds.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Of course! I did not look far enough. Still, I expected all solutions to be smaller values of $\alpha$, certainly all with absolute values less than $1.$

Comment: @Omer I think it should be the inverse of the slope that satisfies the tangent identity. In your notation, it would be $\alpha\tan(1/\alpha) = 1$. When you make a sketch, you can see that, for example, on the $+x$ side, a point around the first upward sine peak can share a tangent line with a point around the 2nd downward peak, which slope is negative and its inverse is around -4.49 (the first  root on the negative side of $\tan x = x$). Similarly, another near-1st-peak-point can share a tangent line with a point around the 3rd, and so on.

Comment: The near-1st-peak-point can of course share a tangent with downward peaks on the $-x$ side, which give the positive slopes. The larger the distance between two points the smaller the magnitude the slope is, and the derivative of sine has magnitude always less than one. btw, clearly the question statement means that the line can intersect with the sine curve many times. It is just "a line is tangent to sine at two points", and other intersections are not excluded by this statement.

Comment: Just to clarify: on the $+x$ side, the 2nd downward peak is overall the 4th peak, and the 3rd downward peak is the overall 6th peak. All the two-tangent-points combo are points around the peaks, but obviously with different deviation from the peak.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that as of the time I last visited this question, there is something wrong about it. Inspection of the sine function indicates that if the slope of the line is not zero, the horizontal distance between tangent points is greater than $2\pi,$ while the vertical distance is less than $2.$
So $\lvert \alpha \rvert < \frac 1\pi,$
and the only possible solution of $\tan\alpha=\alpha$ under these constraints is $\alpha=0.$

---

Let’s consider the case $\alpha\neq 0$ with tangent points at $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1).$
As you found, this implies that 
$x_0 = 2\pi k - x_1.$
Therefore $\frac12(x_0 + x_1) = k \pi.$

Let $x_m = k\pi$ and let $g(x) = \sin(x - x_m).$
Then $g(x) = \sin x$ or  $g(x) = -\sin x,$ depending on whether $k$ is even or odd.
Without loss of generality, let $x_0 = x_m - \xi$ and let $x_1= x_m +\xi,$ where $\xi > 0.$
Then the line $y=\alpha x$ is parallel to the original tangent line specified in the problem statement, and $y=\alpha x$ is tangent to $y=g(x)$ at $(-\xi,y_0)$ and at  $(\xi,y_1).$

For even $k,$ we have
\begin{align}
\sin \xi &= g(x) = \alpha \xi,\\
\cos \xi &= g’(x) = \alpha,
\end{align}
and therefore 
$$ \tan \xi = \frac{ \alpha \xi }{  \alpha } = \xi.$$
For odd $k,$ the signs of both $g(x)$ and $g’(x)$ are reversed, and we again have
$ \tan \xi = \xi.$

That is as close as I was able to get to any formula like “$\tan\alpha = \alpha.$”